# Execute linux App from java using ProcessBulder

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, parallel-processing, launcher

I'm trying to run programs starting them from java, the main problem is that many do not start (mainly .AppImage) others open but crash after a very short time, such as JMonkey.sh (the ide), I don't know what I'm wrong ...

```
processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
String exec = "";
exec = DefaultLaunchExec.defaultLaunch.get(app.getExecProgram())+ app.getExecPath();
        
processBuilder.command("/bin/bash","-c",exec); //exec == path of the program
System.out.println("\n"+processBuilder.command());
        
try {

    process = processBuilder.start();
                
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        output.append(line + "\n");
        System.out.println(line);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
        
DefaultLaunchExec.appRunning.remove(this);
```

Comment: Could you post the command please? (Output of `System.out.println("\n"+processBuilder.command());`)

Comment: [/bin/bash, -c, /home/gattolfo/Applications/Tiled-1.8.4-x86_64_45370181d608e5498c38076f1821f989.AppImage]  OR [/bin/bash, -c, /bin/sh "/home/gattolfo/Programmi/jmonkeyplatform/bin/jmonkeyplatform"]
 i simpli take a exec param from .desktop

Comment: Hm, this looks relatively normal, if you don't see any output/exception, I'm out of ideas, sorry

Comment: In no case will you see the reason for any errors as you don't process stderr

Comment: stderr what is that?